# Gnuplot - errorbars

Tags: compiler-errors, gnuplot

I have an error

```
duplicated or contradicting arguments in plot options
```

pointing to w when I use

```
plot  '1T_1.txt' title "{/:Italic T}_1" with points pt 7 ps 0.5 w yerr
```

What is the problem please? Thank you

Comment: Without data and expected outcome it's difficult to assess but anyway, you cannot have `with` twice in your command. So the least thing to do is `...ps 0.5, "" w yerr`

Comment: There is a simpler answer. The "with yerrorbars" plot style includes both points and errorbars already so there is no need to say "with points".   In general the plot style should come first, followed by details such as pointtype and title.   So `plot FILE ... with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 title "whatever"`